# How to add new resource file to WPF project in Rider

Tags: rider

Is there any "easy" (drag-and-drop) method to add a new file to `Resources.resx` to the WPF project in [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/)? The only way I found is to add file to `Resources` folder and then open `Resources.resx` in XML format and add this:

```xml
<data name="name_of_resource" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
  <value>..\Resources\file_name.ext;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
</data>
```

It's not very hard to add one file like this but when I have to add many files it's more complicated and time-consuming than in Visual Studio where I can just open resources in designer mode, and do drag-and-drop to add new files.

Answer (score 2):

No easy solution I know of, this is a rather old question but you could always use Visual Studio to add the resources and then go back to Rider. That's a solution I've found to work.